# Why isn't my list popping up?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm having trouble finding the reason why my navigation menu is not popping up when I hover over "English". The other menu pop up without problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/B6ZcG/

Can someone help me find the error?

Comment: for me there's only "my account" which is popping

Comment: Define "popping up" What do you want it to do?

Comment: Like "My Account" it should have a sub menu that pops out when I hover over it. English should have other languages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hovering `<li class="top">` element needs to include (wrap) the child `<ul>` containing all the language links. Since its pretty hard to explain how to find the error here the updated code on jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/B6ZcG/2/

Answer (score 1):

You had a rouge `</li>` in your markup

```
<li class="top"><a href="http://bin.xxx/?op=change_lang&lang=english"><span class="trf trf-english"></span>English</a></li>
<ul>
```

Should be

```
<li class="top"><a href="http://bin.xxx/?op=change_lang&lang=english"><span class="trf trf-english"></span>English</a>
    <ul>...
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B6ZcG/1/)